# Reusing variables inside functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, syntax

Total beginner here, the first code below doesn't give any errors and gives the intended output. But the in the second, one I am using y in the inputs of the function and re-using it below as a variable(*is that even a variable?*) in place of var0.
*Shouldn't this give a syntax error? Why is it ok?*

```
def x(y):

    var0 = y + [2]

    print(var0)

c = [1,2,3]

x(c)
```

---

```
def x(y):

    y = y + [2]

    print(y)

c = [1,2,3]

x(c)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to update variables in place, this seems normal to me.

Comment: What would the *syntax* error be for using `y` this way?

Comment: Most languages rooted in [imperative programming](https://mortoray.com/2017/05/10/what-is-imperative-programming/) can use function arguments as local variables, Python among them.

Comment: The term *variable* implies that its value can change - as opposed to a *constant* for a value that doesn't change (Python doesn't have constants). What you're doing is changing `y`'s value and it's fine.

Comment: @Woodford thanks I treated y as a constant that can't be overwritten, I understand it now

Comment: For what it is worth, it does not seem unreasonable to me that someone would assume that function parameters are not mutable. As a general rule, I try to implement functions such that they don't mutate their parameters, almost certainly so when such a mutation would result in side effects outside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it works is because the y parameter is in the local scope of the function. That means it can be **set** and **retrieved** from **anywhere inside that function**.

In functions, parameter values (arguments) are stored in a Symbol Table (Think of it as a spreadsheet filled with variable names and variable values) within the function itself when it is run.

The first version of the function would have this Symbol Table:

```
Name       |      Value
-----------------------
y          [1,2,3]
var0       [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

The second version of the function would have this Symbol Table:

```
--Before re-assignment-
Name       |      Value
-----------------------
y          [1,2,3]
```

When you overwrite the value of y, you are in effect changing the existing value in the symbol table:

```
--After re-assignment--
Name       |      Value
-----------------------
y          [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

TLDR;
Function arguments can be treated like any other variables in this context.

Comment: Ooh that's really cool, I thought y as a constant even though even I myself called it a variable lol. Thank you

Comment: Another cool feature is if y is an object that exists in a different scope, and you changed it in the function's scope, the value is affected in the outer scope as well, like using pointers in C, this is considered: Call by Reference

Comment: I got half of that. But what you said wouldn't be the case if the "outer scope" is positioned upper to the function's scope right? Because the function would be executed after the outer scope is executed thus overwriting y's value?

Comment: Here's an actual example of function side-effects. The don't work with primitives because those are call by value, not by reference. https://replit.com/@JordanRenaud/LightgreySturdyActivecell#main.py

Comment: I see, are there other nuances like this that I need to be aware of? Or rather, where can I search for such things on the web?

Comment: Search function side effects, pass by value (python specific). Also, you can return more than one value from a function if you split them by commas, really cool stuff compared to other languages like Java.

Comment: Do not forget to choose an accepted answer if you feel your question has been answered!